# Managed VM Issue? Frequently found error log about VmApiProxyDelegate (using Datastore API, TaskQueue API) on AppEngine Managed VM instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-managed-vm

I'm using the Google AppEngine Managed VM/Java since March 2015.  Everything is work well.  But after September, October 2015,  I noticed I 've seen the error log of "com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate" in Managed VM instance log frequently.

2 groups of error log I noticed.

The first one is related to datastore operation on Managed VM instance. It happens on

- datastore_v3.Get().
- datastore_v3.RunQuery()
- datastore_v3.Put()
- memcache.Get().

Sample of stacktrace I saw in the log is below ... (sample below is for datastore_v3.Put())

> com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate runSyncCall: HTTP
>   ApiProxy I/O error for datastore_v3.Put: Read timed out
>
> com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RPCFailedException: The remote RPC
>   to the application server failed for the call datastore_v3.Get().     at
>   com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.runSyncCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:182)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.makeApiCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:141)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.access$000(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:47)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate$MakeSyncCall.call(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:375)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate$MakeSyncCall.call(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:351)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

So, when this error occurred, at application level (my code), I got RPCFailedException  but right now, I've not handled it with retry mechanism  ( I only use retry mechanism for ConcurrentModificationException with App Engine Datastore API)

The second group of error log is about TaskQueue API on the Managed VM.

The error message I got is ...

> com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate runSyncCall: Error
>   body: RPC Error: /StubbyService.Send to (unknown) : APP_ERROR(2)

When tracing , the detailed stacktrace is ...

> com.wat_suttiwat.batchengine.job.PushNotificationTaskExecutor
>   executeTask: The remote RPC to the application server failed for the
>   call taskqueue.QueryAndOwnTasks().
>   com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RPCFailedException: The remote RPC
>   to the application server failed for the call
>   taskqueue.QueryAndOwnTasks().     at
>   com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.runSyncCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:161)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.makeApiCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:141)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.access$000(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:47)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate$MakeSyncCall.call(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:375)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate$MakeSyncCall.call(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:351)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"RPCFailedException" exception raised at the application level (like the first case).  And I noticed the Google AppEngine front-end instance (not the managed-vm instance), it work as usual no error about these.

So my question is

1. Should I add retry-mechanism for RPCFailedException ? Is it useful to add retry?  I don't see any documentation from the Google AppEngine document on this.
2. Does anyone has the same issues with me?  If yes,  please help to vote the issue at this issue-tracker (#12393):   https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=12393
3. If you have any workaround,  please share.

Thanks so much

Comment: OK as checked in github,   seems Google 's working on this bug.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-runtime/issues/22

Comment: I've tried to star the issue but it give me a 403 error. Btw I think that the retry-mechanism is pretty unuseful because the error happens after a timeout of 60 seconds!